# NServiceBus - Retrieve Saga Status in MVC 3 Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nservicebus

I am using an NServiceBus saga to handle a long running business process. I have an MVC 3 application that is accessed from multiple web servers behind a load balancer.

The goal is that I can have the user initiate the process, and I want to be able to determine the state of the saga.

What is the best way to do this? I have a feeling I will need some sort of persistant storage, but I really do not want to have to hit my database a lot as there is the potential of running thousands of this particular saga per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build in to your Saga step that when the status changes, it Bus.Sends() the status to another endpoint that updates a cache or PVM your web app could look at.  This endpoint could communicate on other channels to the user, such as email.  Pushing this off to another endpoint will keep your Saga flowing.

Comment: I actually did something similar to this. I had a memcached server setup and I just pushed the changes to that. This allowed my web servers (already talking to the memcached server), to grab the changes. Just used appropriate keys to quickly find my cache record.

Answer (score 0):

The saga can publish events to publicize the status of things. Even without the requirement of an MVC app "checking in," this is probably a good idea anyway.

Your web app could subscribe to this event and update in-memory state, which web requests could check and display.  Of course this will not survive a web process restart.

To deal with this, the saga could support an "I forgot what you said, please resend" command. The MVC app would send this on webapp start (if knowing is important enough) or on-demand. Then the Saga would respond with a status report to just that server via Bus.Reply() to just the server that's not up-to-date.